# Buoyancy when front crawling

Tags: swimming

I am very close to negative buoyancy.

When learning to swim front craw if I exhale my head will sink down very quickly.

Is there a technique to keep my upper body at the right angle when doing front crawl ?

Answer (score 1):

Engage your core. Try to focus on keeping the top of your head, butt and ankles at the surface of the water. When breathing, don’t take huge breaths. This is one of the most fatal flaws. Expansion of your chest cavity drops your legs. You want to take just enough air such that in 2-3 strokes you’ve pretty much emptied your chest cavity.

Press your chest in the water too. I would recommend binge watching Effortless Swimming on YouTube.